# Quartz.NET scheduling issues in Autofac container

Tags: c#, .net-core, inversion-of-control, autofac, quartz.net

I have an Autofac container that I wish to add a lifetime Quartz.NET scheduler to using [Autofac.Extras.Quartz](https://github.com/alphacloud/Autofac.Extras.Quartz). With the code as is below, a Quartz scheduler is instantiated with the set properties, but it seems the scheduler is killed off after the initialization step.

I first call `Initialize` from my `Program.cs` to create a new container for `MyModule`.

`MyModuleStartup.cs`

```
private static IContainer? _container;
public static void Initialize()
{
    var containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();
    containerBuilder.RegisterModule(new QuartzModule());
    _container = containerBuilder.Build();
    MyCompositionRoot.SetContainer(_container);
    QuartzStartup.Initialize(_container);
}
```

I register and configure `QuartzAutofacFactoryModule` and `QuartzAutofacJobsModule` as described in the package's documentation.

`QuartzModule.cs`

```
public class QuartzModule : Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        var schedulerConfiguration = new NameValueCollection { { "quartz.scheduler.instanceName", "MyScheduler" } };
        builder.RegisterModule(new QuartzAutofacFactoryModule
        {
            ConfigurationProvider = _ => schedulerConfiguration
        });
        builder.RegisterModule(new QuartzAutofacJobsModule(typeof(MyJob).Assembly));
    }
}
```

I then initialize Quartz.NET.

`QuartzModule.cs`

```
internal static class QuartzStartup
{
    private static IScheduler? _scheduler;

    internal static void Initialize(IContainer container)
    {
        _scheduler = container.Resolve<IScheduler>();
        _scheduler.Start().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    
        var myJob = JobBuilder.Create<MyJob>().Build();

        var myTrigger = TriggerBuilder.Create().StartNow()
            .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x.WithIntervalInSeconds(5).RepeatForever()).Build();

        // I can confirm here that the instance name property of scheduler is MyScheduler
        _scheduler.ScheduleJob(myJob, myTrigger).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

    }
}
```

MyJob is a simple `IJob` class with a single debug statement in its overridden `Execute` method (with a debug on the line that is never hit).

`MyJob.cs`

```
public abstract class MyJob: IJob
{
    public async Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        // Based on debugging, this line is never hit.
        Debug.WriteLine($"Job running at {DateTime.Now.ToString()}");
    }
}
```

How can I properly instantiate a lifetime instance of Quartz.NET withing my container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `QuartzAutofacJobsModule` doesn't register the class `MyJob` because it is `abstract` since abstract classes can't be instantiated. Remove that and everything works as expected.

```cs
public class MyJob: IJob
{
    public async Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        // Based on debugging, this line is never hit.
        Debug.WriteLine($"Job running at {DateTime.Now.ToString()}");

        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Make sure your program doesn't exit before the first trigger fires. I've added a temporary delay at the end and made proper use of `async`/`await` just so the sample code you provided doesn't exit immediately.

```cs
internal static async Task Initialize(IContainer container)
{
    _scheduler = container.Resolve<IScheduler>();
    await _scheduler.Start();
    
    var myJob = JobBuilder.Create<MyJob>().Build();

    var myTrigger = TriggerBuilder.Create().StartNow()
        .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x.WithIntervalInSeconds(5).RepeatForever()).Build();

    // I can confirm here that the instance name property of scheduler is MyScheduler
    await _scheduler.ScheduleJob(myJob, myTrigger);
    await Task.Delay(10000);
}
```

Comment: The removal of the abstract keyword did it. Was able to confirm my program doesn't exit after the first trigger due to the Autofac container, so I was able to still get the awaited result of `ScheduleJob`. Cheers!